# Select column names which has a default data

Tags: oracle

I have a table having 150 columns. I need to select the column names which has a default data is set('`DATA_DEFAULT`' is NOT NULL). Is it possible to query the column name and its corresponding default data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select owner
,      table_name
,      column_name
,      data_type
,      data_length
,      data_precision
,      data_scale
,      nullable
,      data_default
from   all_tab_columns
where  table_name = 'your_table_name'
and    data_default is not null
;
```

To check all tables containing a column with data_default:

```
select owner
,      table_name
,      wm_concat(column_name)
,      count(*)
from   all_tab_columns
where  data_default is not null
group
by     owner
,      table_name
having count(*) > 0
```

Comment: + `and table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'` to select the columns of the particular table

Comment: @Patrick Hofman, @ShinTakezou ,How can I change the query to select the table names from the DB which has at least one column having `data_default is not null` ?

Comment: @PatrickHofman : Showing `invalid number of arguments` for `COUNT()`. Replaced the same with `COUNT(*)` and is working fine. Thanks.